# ClientToScreen API functions returns not the expected point

Tags: c#, winapi

I'm currently designing a function that searches a subpicture on a picture of a window. If the search was successful, it clicks on the center of this subpicture. Strangely, it always clicks a below the expected position.

The search algorithm works correct - I still checked it. The provided coordinates for the function are correct. But the function ClientToScreen works strange. For example:

My subpicture was found at x = 352, y = 70 - the coordinates are relative to the left upper corner of the window.
The left upper corner of my window is at x = 91, y = 303 relative to the screen.
So, I expected for the coordinates to click on, relative to the screen as follows:

```
X_Click = Window.Left + X_Click_rel2Wnd = 352 + 91= 443;
Y_Click = Window.Top + Y_Click_rel2Wnd = 70 + 303 = 373;
```

The function returns:
447 / 396

It looks like this picture shows:
[image]

Anybody has an idea, whats wrong?

Below the code:

```
public static class ClickOnPointTool{
private const uint MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
private const uint MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
private const uint MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
private const uint MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;
private const uint MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEDOWN = 0x00000020;
private const uint MOUSEEVENTF_MIDDLEUP = 0x00000040;

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct TPoint{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ClientToScreen(System. IntPtr hWnd, ref TPoint lpPoint);

#pragma warning disable 649
internal struct INPUT{
    public System.UInt32 Type;
    public MOUSEKEYBDHARDWAREINPUT Data;
}

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
internal static extern uint SendInput(uint nInputs, [System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(System.Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPArray), System.Runtime.InteropServices.In] INPUT[] pInputs, int cbSize);

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Explicit)]
internal struct MOUSEKEYBDHARDWAREINPUT{
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.FieldOffset(0)]
    public MOUSEINPUT Mouse;
}

internal struct MOUSEINPUT{
    public System.Int32 X;
    public System.Int32 Y;
    public System.UInt32 MouseData;
    public System.UInt32 Flags;
    public System.UInt32 Time;
    public System.IntPtr ExtraInfo;
}

#pragma warning restore 649
public static void ClickOnPoint(System.IntPtr wndHandle, int x, int y, bool KeepCursor = false, bool RightButton = false, bool DoubleClick = false, System.Data.DataTable WndBoundings = null){
    int nTimes = 0;
    TPoint clientPoint;
    clientPoint.X = x;
    clientPoint.Y = y;

    System.Drawing.Point oldPos = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position;

    //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Click to " + clientPoint.X + " / " + clientPoint.Y + "");
    if(DoubleClick){nTimes = 2;}else{nTimes = 1;}

    /// get screen coordinates
    if(WndBoundings == null){
        ClientToScreen(wndHandle, ref clientPoint);
    }else{
        clientPoint.X += (int)WndBoundings.Rows[0]["Left"];
        clientPoint.Y += (int)WndBoundings.Rows[0]["Top"];
    }
    //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Click to " + clientPoint.X + " / " + clientPoint.Y + "");

    /// set cursor on coords, and press mouse
    System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(clientPoint.X, clientPoint.Y);

    INPUT inputMouseDown = new INPUT();
    inputMouseDown.Type = 0; /// input type mouse
    if(RightButton){
        inputMouseDown.Data.Mouse.Flags = MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN; ///right button down
    }else{
        inputMouseDown.Data.Mouse.Flags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN; /// left button down
    }
    INPUT inputMouseUp = new INPUT();
    inputMouseUp.Type = 0; /// input type mouse
    if(RightButton){
        inputMouseUp.Data.Mouse.Flags = MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP; /// right button up
    }else{
        inputMouseUp.Data.Mouse.Flags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP; /// left button up
    }

    var inputs = new INPUT[] { inputMouseDown, inputMouseUp };

    for(int i=0;i<nTimes;i++){
        SendInput((uint)inputs.Length, inputs, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT)));
    }

    /// return mouse 
    if(!KeepCursor){System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = oldPos;}
}
```

}

Comment: Seems to be about the Height of the window title off .... curious .. if I were you I would investigate that ...

Comment: What's the overall aim here? For *most* problems in this space, there are better approaches than simulating input events. E.g. there's a whole load of APIs created for accessibility purposes.

Comment: *the coordinates are relative to the left upper corner of the window* Looks like the coordinates you pass to the `ClientToScreen` are not "client" coordinates as the `ClientToScreen` expects. The client coordinates are relative to the client rectangle of the window, which excludes the title and border.

Comment: I'm going to use `GetWindowRect` to calculate the correct coordinates - this functions seams to provide the correct window size including its title. I just wante to understand. Thank you all...

Comment: Why are you even fiddling with faking input? Use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/ui-automation/ui-automation-overview), and be done with it. Among other things, this allows you to automate an application, that is not the foreground application. It's also immune to changes in the UI layout, or UI state (like a hidden ribbon bar). And then there's a .NET wrapper, so you don't have to P/Invoke, and get it wrong.

Comment: @llnspectable: I'm writing a code implemented in our RPA tool. Therefore, no third party libraries are desired. Don't ask me - not my decision.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all. This runs well:

```
    private static System.Drawing.Point GetWindowCornerLU(System.IntPtr hWnd){
    if(hWnd == System.IntPtr.Zero){throw new System.Exception("ERROR: Window handle is not referenced!");}

    WindowHandle.User32.Rect rect = new WindowHandle.User32.Rect();
    WindowHandle.User32.GetWindowRect(hWnd, ref rect);
    return new System.Drawing.Point(rect.left, rect.top);
}

#pragma warning restore 649
public static void ClickOnPoint(System.IntPtr wndHandle, int x, int y, bool KeepCursor = false, bool RightButton = false, bool DoubleClick = false){
    int nTimes = 0;
    TPoint clientPoint;
    clientPoint.X = x;
    clientPoint.Y = y;

    System.Drawing.Point oldPos = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position;

    //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Click to " + clientPoint.X + " / " + clientPoint.Y + "");
    if(DoubleClick){nTimes = 2;}else{nTimes = 1;}

    /// get screen coordinates
    //ClientToScreen(wndHandle, ref clientPoint);
    System.Drawing.Point prtLU = GetWindowCornerLU(wndHandle);
    clientPoint.X += prtLU.X;
    clientPoint.Y += prtLU.Y;
    //System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Click to " + clientPoint.X + " / " + clientPoint.Y + "");

    /// set cursor on coords, and press mouse
    System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(clientPoint.X, clientPoint.Y);

    INPUT inputMouseDown = new INPUT();
    inputMouseDown.Type = 0; /// input type mouse
    if(RightButton){
        inputMouseDown.Data.Mouse.Flags = MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN; ///right button down
    }else{
        inputMouseDown.Data.Mouse.Flags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN; /// left button down
    }
    INPUT inputMouseUp = new INPUT();
    inputMouseUp.Type = 0; /// input type mouse
    if(RightButton){
        inputMouseUp.Data.Mouse.Flags = MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP; /// right button up
    }else{
        inputMouseUp.Data.Mouse.Flags = MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP; /// left button up
    }

    var inputs = new INPUT[] { inputMouseDown, inputMouseUp };

    for(int i=0;i<nTimes;i++){
        SendInput((uint)inputs.Length, inputs, System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT)));
    }

    /// return mouse 
    if(!KeepCursor){System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = oldPos;}
}
```

}